# Python 2.7: Print to File

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

Why does trying to print directly to a file instead of `sys.stdout` produce the following syntax error:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f1=open('./testfile', 'w+')
>>> print('This is a test', file=f1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('This is a test', file=f1)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From help(__builtins__) I have the following info:

```
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

So what would be the right syntax to change the standard stream print writes to?

I know that there are different maybe better ways to write to file but I really don't get why this should be a syntax error...

A nice explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure? `print()` is python 3.x built-in function, while `print` is python < 3.x operator. The post shows `2.7.2+`.

Comment: Did you `from __future__ import print_function` ?  In Python < 3, print is a statement:

Comment: No! I didn't. Of course you are right. That solves the problem. Dammit! So the documented print in help(\__builtins__) is the future (3.x) version of print which has a different syntax. Thank you very much and you too, kachik

Comment: IMO, `help(__builtins__)` displaying that at all is a bug.

Comment: ...although, investigating further, python 2.7.2 *does* have a built-in print function, you just can't access it easily normally (`__builtins__.__dict__['print'](value, file=f1)` does work, though).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you want to use the `print` function in Python 2, you have to import from `__future__`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

But you can have the same effect without using the function, too:

```
print >>f1, 'This is a test'
```

Comment: The downside to using `print >>` is that it then won't work in Python 3.  The import is the best way to make cross-version compatible code.

Answer (score 73):

print is a keyword in python 2.X. You should use the following:

```
f1=open('./testfile', 'w+')
f1.write('This is a test')
f1.close()
```

Comment: You need to add '\n' to make this equivalent to print.

Answer (score 44):

`print(args, file=f1)` is the python 3.x syntax.
For python 2.x use `print >> f1, args`.

Comment: I think you should also mention `from __future__ import print_function`. Then you can use the clear notation in both, Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'` with your python3 syntax

Comment: @Suncatcher, you are probably trying to pass string containing file name as f1 instead of the actual file object. You need to open file for writing first: `f1 = open('path_to_your_file', 'w')`

Comment: Yeah, I thought it should be filename, not file object.

Answer (score 15):

This will redirect your 'print' output to a file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("file.txt", "w+")
print "this line will redirect to file.txt"
```

Comment: is it monkey patching?

Comment: That overwrites `stdout` for all future writes, too - that's a problematic side-effect.

Answer (score 13):

You can export print statement to file without changing any code. Simply open a terminal windows and run your code in this way:

```
python yourcode.py >> log.txt
```

Comment: That redirects _all_ output, rather than the single print statement!

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.0+, `print` is a **function**, which you'd call with `print(...)`. In earlier version, `print` is a **statement**, which you'd make with `print ...`.

To print to a file in Python earlier than 3.0, you'd do:

```
print >> f, 'what ever %d', i
```

The `>>` operator directs print to the file `f`.

Comment: I'd like to print a whole array to the file. If I use your code, only the head and tail of array was printed, like the output from terminal. How to print all array lines to the file?

Comment: @Sigur "Like the output from terminal" Sorry, but the bug's elsewhere. You're not telling Python to print the whole thing, which is why it's not.