# Pycharm cannot recognize print option args

Tags: python, printing, pycharm

I am using PyCharm CE 2016.2 and python interpreter 3.5. When I tried to type the following in console, the file is generated with '123'.

```
>>> with open('man_data.txt', 'w') as data:
        print('123', file=data)
```

However, when I put the same statement into a test.py file and try to run it using subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py']), it gives

```
>>> subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])
    File "test.py", line 2
    print('123', file=data)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
1
```

Does anyone has any clues? Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Python 2` is started when you call `subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])`.

Try to change to `subprocess.call(['python3', 'test.py'])` or update the script as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316023/python-2-7-print-to-file).

Comment: thank you so much!! after spending hours to debug the cause, i finally have this out of my way.