# [Python]: how to print results on a output file instead of the URL

Tags: python

The code is printing results to the a URL:

```
    result = test2
    try:
        resultData = {'l': result}
        r = requests.post('http://site.com/a.php', data = resultData)
    except:
        pass
    self.testingWP(test2, session, ret)
    return ret
```

Instead of printing results on the URL, I would like to get the results in > output.txt

Thanks

Comment: This code is not *printing* anything....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: Print to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316023/python-2-7-print-to-file)