# how to print the output to a text file in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

```
import nltk
from urllib import request

url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"
response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read().decode('utf8')
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
tokens
```

In the above code the output is in 'tokens' in the form of list. How to copy this list into a text file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directing print output to a .txt file in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571560/directing-print-output-to-a-txt-file-in-python-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2.7: Print to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316023/python-2-7-print-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this:

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in tokens:
        f.write(i)
```